# How to calculate confidence intervals for the scale parameter of a parametric survival model?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival

I use R code to create the following AFT model

```
survregLogNormal <- survreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog.ps + rx, ovarian, dist = "loglogistic")
```

Next, I want to calculate the confidence interval of the estimated parameters / model coefficients with

```
confint( survregLogNormal  )
```

What I receive is the following output:

```
                 2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)  3.9390699 8.3829255
ecog.ps     -1.3888480 0.7167439
rx          -0.3510217 1.7600539
```

Interestingly, the CI for the scale parameter is not part of the output. Is there any way in R to make `confint()` to return also the CI for the scale parameter, which one can see in the model's summary:

```
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(X, pain) ~ sex, data = mydata, dist = "loglogistic")
             Value Std. Error     z      p
(Intercept)  5.639      0.153 36.96 <2e-16
sex          0.300      0.179  1.67  0.095
Log(scale)  -1.221      0.134 -9.14 <2e-16

Scale= 0.295 

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `survreg.object` [manual page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf), the `var` component of an object returned by `survreg()` is "the variance-covariance matrix for the parameters, including the log(scale) parameter(s)." So the square root of the diagonal element  for `log(scale)` in that `var` component gives its standard error, and you use the standard 1.96 factor for converting standard error limits to 95% CI under the assumption of asymptotic normality (as for the other parameter estimates: those are z-values shown).

It's possible for a `survreg()` function call to specify a fixed value of `scale` instead of estimating it from the data. In that case there would be no standard error for it; perhaps that's why `confint()` doesn't directly return a CI value.